# How to show array inside of other object array in Collection View Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin

I have a JSON response

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634b6be99237b35a9aa80dd5"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-10-16T02:27:44.766+0000"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-10-16T02:26:49.276+0000"),
    "firstName" : "Romulo",
    "lastName" : "Calderon",
    "email" : "romuloacd@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "0962908538",
    "description" : "Hoy u",
    "user" : ObjectId("5aee09ef88b9ac4289109574"),
    "appoinmentAt" : ISODate("2022-10-17T14:00:00.000+0000"),
    "status" : [
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-08-22T20:15:48.672+0000"),
            "value" : "DEUDA",
            "name" : "WITHOUT_PAYING"
        },
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-08-22T20:15:48.672+0000"),
            "value" : "PAGADO",
            "name" : "PAID_OUT"
        }
    ],
    "total" : 45.36,
    "iva" : NumberInt(12),
    "value" : 40.5,
    "time" : NumberInt(30),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

from an API call, I already show the most fields in collection without any problem, but I have inside the response another array defined in this model:

```
namespace App1.Models
{
    public class TicketsApi
    {
        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Idtickets { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("user")]
        public string Idusuario { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("firstName")]
        public string Nombresolicitante { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("lastName")]
        public string Apellidosolicitante { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string CorreoSolicitante { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Motivoconsulta { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("phone")]
        public string CelularSolicitante { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string ValorSolicitante { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string TiempoSolicitante { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("status")]

        public Estado[] Status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("appoinmentAt")]
        public DateTime CitaSolicitante { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("createdAt")]
        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

    }

    public class Estado
    {


        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string EstadoPago { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string EstadoTransaccion { get; set; }

       


    }
}
```

In the front I have this xaml code, and all the field works good, but after many researches I don't know how load correctly the array Estado define in TicketsAPi.
This is the code that runs OK, thanks to Jason and the solution of the problem

```
                 <CollectionView 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSubasta}"
                            SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="#eee"
                               BorderColor="#ddd"
                               Padding="20">
                            <StackLayout x:DataType="model:TicketsApi">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Nombresolicitante, StringFormat='Nombres: {0:N}'}"
                                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                       FontSize="14" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Apellidosolicitante, StringFormat='Apellidos: {0:N}'}"
                                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                       FontSize="14" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding CitaSolicitante, StringFormat='Fecha de consulta: {0}'}"
                                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                       FontSize="16" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding TiempoSolicitante, StringFormat='Tiempo: {0:N} minutos'}"
                                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                       FontSize="13" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding ValorSolicitante, StringFormat='Valor Consulta: {0:N} dólares (incluye IVA)'}"
                                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                       FontSize="13" />
                                <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Status}"
                                             
                                              >
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="model:Estado" >
                                            <Label Text="{Binding EstadoTransaccion }" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

I try though to show the correctly the fields inside "Estado" array which is inside TicketsApi model

Comment: Use a [grouped CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping)

Comment: you can also use a nested `ListView`, but the proper binding expression would be `Text="{Binding EstadoTransaccion}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) to display a collection of items without wrapping it in CollectionView.

Please refer to the following code:

```
   <CollectionView 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSubasta}"
                        SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="#eee"
                           BorderColor="#ddd"
                           Padding="20">
                        <StackLayout x:DataType="model:TicketsApi">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Nombresolicitante, StringFormat='Nombres: {0:N}'}"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                   FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Apellidosolicitante, StringFormat='Apellidos: {0:N}'}"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                   FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding CitaSolicitante, StringFormat='Fecha de consulta: {0}'}"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                   FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding TiempoSolicitante, StringFormat='Tiempo: {0:N} minutos'}"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                   FontSize="13" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ValorSolicitante, StringFormat='Valor Consulta: {0:N} dólares (incluye IVA)'}"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                   FontSize="13" />
                           
                    <!-- add code here -->

                <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Status}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EstadoTransaccion}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Comment: this is an example of the json response structure .. this response is DESEREALIZE and the field like normal strings show OK.. the problem persist even use your code...

Comment: i modify the question an add the structure of the json response with example

Comment: The binded property should be the properties of the inner model of list `Status`,from the json you shared, it should be `createdAt`,`value`  and `name`.

Comment: we run your code on the solution but the error is EstadoTransaccion not found on App1.Models.TicketsApi

Comment: You need to set the DataTemplate’s DataType

Comment: i use the jsonproperty on the model... but i try with your recomensation and i use createdAt,value and name but the same result

Comment: You can try to debug to see the special property name and value of the inner item from list (`Status`).

Comment: men you are the best... thanks... all is OK

Comment: Congrats. Have a nice day. :)